# PHP array to JavaScript using JSON object - returns null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I've got an array in PHP which I'm passing to my view for use within the JavaScript.

So what I've got is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [tones] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 114
            [sleep_session_id] => 55
            [responded_to] => 
            [in_bed] => 1
            [created] => 1316443267104
            [inserted] => 2011-09-19 14:43:04
        )
    )
)

$(function () {
    var tones = $.parseJSON(<?php echo json_encode($this->tones); ?>);
    alert(tones);
});
```

Which results in something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var tones = $.parseJSON([{"id":114,"sleep_session_id":55}]);
        alert(tones);
    });
</script>
```

All I'm getting back is null, the jQuery is definately loaded and I've checked the JSON in jsonlint.com and it appears valid

Hope you can help me out

Andy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your server-side data are in JSON, there's no need to use `$.parseJSON` in Javascript.

```
$(function () {
    var tones = <?php echo json_encode($this->tones); ?>;
    alert(tones);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function () {
        var tones = $.parseJSON('[{"id":114,"sleep_session_id":55}]');
        alert(tones);
    });
```

Comment: jesus, i must be half asleep still :D thanks guys. So silly when something like this knacks you off enough to post on StackOverflow only to realise that you've asked a really really stupid question :) thanks again all. I ended up just echoing out php json_encode on it. Seemed neater and i dont trust js :D

Answer (score 2):

[parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) parses a **JSON string**, so enclose your encoded array in quotes :

```
$(function () {
    var tones = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($this->tones); ?>');
    alert(tones);
});
```

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/kSBKD/)